# MySQL does FK reduce insert/update operations?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

Does anybody know, does FK reduce insert/update operations in MySQL?
I use engine INNODB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Having a FK on a table implicitly creates (and maintains) an index.
- When doing certain write operations, the FK's implicit `INDEX` is checked to verify the existence of the appropriate row in the other table.  This is a minor performance burden during writes.
- When doing `SELECT ... JOIN` for which you failed to explicitly provide the appropriate index, the implicit index produced by some FK may come into play.  This is a big benefit to some `JOINs`, but does not require an FK, since you could have added the `INDEX` manually.
- If the FK definition includes `ON DELETE or UPDATE`, then even more work may be done, especially for `CASCADE`.  The effect of `CASCADE` can be achieved with a `SELECT` plus more code -- but not as efficiently as letting `CASCADE` do the work.
- FKs are limited in what they can do.  Stackoverflow is littered with question like "How can I get an FK to do X?"

Does any of this sound like "reducing insert/update operations"?

Answer (score 1):

> does FK reduce insert/update operations in MySQL?

It's not about *MySQL* but **yes** it does. Creating FK on a column will create a secondary index and thus upon DML operation those indexes needs to be updated as well in order to have a correct table statistics. So that, DB optimizer can generate a correct and efficient query plan

Comment: Thank you for answer, could you provide some documents where i could read more about it? I think it is true for every DB, but i want to know how does it work with MySQL.

Comment: @VIQ, sure ... just search for *FK or index + mysql* in Google ... you will get MySQL official doc. go through it